# Making EditText editable or not editable according to CheckBox

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-checkbox

I want to make an EditText object is focusable or unfocusable according to the CheckBox's situation.But these codes are not working.I can't see an error?How to do this?

```
atasozuTahmin.setFocusable(false);

tahminAcKapaCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked == true){
                atasozuTahmin.setFocusable(true);
            }else{
                atasozuTahmin.setFocusable(false);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: you want to set focussable or set foccussed?

Comment: I want to make uneditable the edittext.I will correct now.

Comment: if you want to make it uneditable .. then the keywrod is editable .. not focusable

Answer (score 1):

Use instead:

```
atasozuTahmin.setFocusableInTouchMode(isChecked);
atasozuTahmin.setEditable(isChecked);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be acheived by setting keyListener to null

```
atasozuTahmin.setKeyListener(null);
```